# Multi Client Game Server tips

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I just finished writing a simple board game for my college assignment. The game is very similar to checkers where players 2 players can move their pieces during their turns.

My current task is making the game playable online, via a game server and game client.

I followed some online tutorials on multiThreaded servers and I have these 2 bare bone classes:

```
class NetWorkServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NetWorkServer( QObject *parent = 0);
    void StartServer();

private:

    std::vector<ClientThread * > _clientThreads;

protected:
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);

};




class ClientThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QTcpSocket *socket;
    QTcpSocket * pairSocket = nullptr;
    int socketDescriptor;
    bool _isHost;

public:
    explicit ClientThread(int ID, QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();
    bool isHost();

signals:

    void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketerror);

public slots:
    void readyRead();
    void disconnected();

};
```

This works but before i continue further i need some tips.

the way i want it to work is as following :

- A player can Host a game on the server, he will then provide all the parameters for the game creation.
- A player can join a hosted game, if of course there is a hosted game on the server

And this the part where i am lost, how am i suppose to proceed from here. What would be the best way to match 2 threads of the 2  different clients that are currently in the same game? should i create another class for this (like GameSession for example)?

Any additional reading materiel on this topic would also be very welcome.

Comment: @ddriver: Broad questions are no more on topic on programmers.se than they are here.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to match 2 threads of the 2 different
>   clients that are currently in the same game?

It is the server that does that. The server controls the game, the clients do nothing more than to send requests and receive results. For example, if your client moves, it only sends a move command to the server, the server processes that, makes the move and informs the clients that the move has been made to update GUI. All actions take place on the server, which is what synchronizes all the clients so that there is always only one single state of the game.

Good game design dictates you should already have a `Game` class, what you need to make that a dedicated server is to implement a layer of communication to drive the game. I assume right now you have game, input and GUI crammed together. You need to isolate / abstract / encapsulate the game from the player input and the GUI, so you can have multiple clients sending user events to the game server, and the game server sending updates to the multiple GUIs, ran by each client.

In fact, it is proper practice to have that level of encapsulation of responsibility right from the start, whether or not you plan on making a multiplayer server game. A good design is flexible and powerful, making design changes later on is difficult and often breaks code.

I'd also recommend you implement a more abstract means of communication, regardless of which side is the connecting and which one is the connected. Then it is a simple matter to implement player and server commands, which serialize for network transmission and are deserealized and processed on the receiving side.

Network wise you can go two courses:

UDP - typically used by fast pace, real time games, such as first person shooters. UDP is connectionless, low latency but unreliable and supports multicast and broadcast, so in Qt when you read a UDP datagram, you can provide the IP address and port of the host you expect. The negotiation of the "connection" will inform the server of the client IP and port, and from then it is up to you to only intercept data from those locations.

TCP - more reliable than UDP but this comes with some overhead, there is a distinct connection, a better match for games which require less frequent data transmission, such as turn based games, as is your game. You just keep track of all active connections and iterate them to send data to the clients, there is no multicast in TCP.

In both cases there is usually an initial connection negotiation that happens over TCP. The clients must provide the server IP and port, and once the negotiation connection is established, the data needed to establish the persistent connection is sent and that connection is closed so other clients can negotiate with the server. Ports can't be "shared" or multiplexed, so in the case of TCP the server will have a port dedicated to each active connection plus the negotiation port.

The client connects to the server listen port, and sends a magic number, which basically says "hey I am a indeed client who wants to connect to you" and also handling authentication if any. Then, in the case of UDP you start accepting datagrams from the IP and port of the client, in the case of TCP the server can either connect to the host to establish a connection, or send a dedicated port over the negotiation connection at which the client can establish a persistent connection. It doesn't really matter who initiates the connection.

Comment: Thank for the reply, My game classes are isolated and that's not going to be a problem. What i am currently struggling with is the client-server communications. What i saw online is usually something like 1 server sending info to all clients (echo server). But that's not really what i need here. I need to think of a way to pair 2 threads together, the client that hosted and the client that joined the host, and somehow keep them isolated, so when player in Game1 moves i only send messages to those players and not lets say players in Game2.

Comment: Game servers usually have one port, a "listen" port which is used to negotiate another, persistent connection, after which that port is released so other clients can join in. So the server will have a dedicated connection to each client, and simply iterate the connections and send the data across each one. So only the clients connected to that game will receive game status updates over their dedicated connections.

Comment: @user2302702, I think you didn't understand what @ddriver was saying. If you have a dedicated `Game` class, you will automatically isolate different players into their various games and not have "cross-chatter". At the moment, you have client connections all grouped together in your server class. If instead, your server had a list of `Games`, and you added connections to each game, then you would have the necessary isolation.

Comment: @RobbieE - IMO a single `Server` class should host a single game, now you can still have multiple server classes in the server application running on the server machine.